# how to set foreign key for each files while uploading multiple filels?

Tags: django, foreign-keys

Here I am trying to upload multiple files but it's not working properly.I got problem while storing the foreign key for each files selected ?

I got this error.
`Cannot assign "<property object at 0x04667960>": "MoreImage.image_title" must be a "Gallery" instance.`

models

```
class Gallery(models.Model):
    image_title = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, null=True)
    image_date = models.DateField(blank=True, null=True)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='gallery', default='default.png')
class MoreImage(models.Model):
    image_title = models.ForeignKey(Gallery, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    images = models.ImageField(upload_to='moreimage', default='default.png')
    date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

views

```
def add_more_image(request):
    images = Gallery.objects.all().order_by('-date')
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = MoreImageForm(request.POST or None, request.FILES or None)
        if form.is_valid():
            more = form.save(commit=False)
            for file in request.FILES.getlist('image'):     
                MoreImage.objects.create(image_title=Gallery.pk, images=file)
                #for field in request.FILES.keys():
                #for form_file in request.FILES.getlist(field):
                    #img = MoreImage(image_title_id=Gallery.pk,images=form_file)
                    #img.save()
            more.save()
            messages.success(request, ' Images added.')
            return redirect('admin:add_gallery')
```

MoreImage Form

```
class MoreImageForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = MoreImage
        fields = '__all__'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you shouldn't call **`Gallery.pk`** because it's won't return anything since it's a class. It should be something like **`gallary_instance.pk`**
and I don't think `gallary_instance.pk` will work for you because you've set **`commit=False`** which prevent to save the object into DB.

Try this,

```
def add_more_image(request):
    images = Gallery.objects.all().order_by('-date')
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = MoreImageForm(request.POST or None, request.FILES or None)
        if form.is_valid():
            more = form.save()  # remove commit=False
            for file in request.FILES.getlist('image'):
                MoreImage.objects.create(image_title=more.image_title, images=file)
            messages.success(request, ' Images added.')
            return redirect('admin:add_gallery')
```

Comment: Tried this but i got this error Exception Value: 
Cannot assign "<MoreImage: MoreImage object (22)>": "MoreImage.image_title" must be a "Gallery" instance.

Comment: i just added form in my question

Comment: I've updated the code snippet. try and let me know if any error occurred.